# EAP: create rest client with elytron client-ssl-context

Tags: jboss, resteasy

I know, how to build a ResteasyClient with own SSL context.

```
  builder.sslContext(mySSLcontext);
```

It works fine, e.g from standalone client and/or arquillain tests.
I build the SSL context programmatically, loading truststore etc.

I have a EAR+War (ProjekctA) offering a Rest Service using web.xml:

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ICSCRest</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

and jboss-web.xml

```
  <jboss-web>
    <server-instance>default-server</server-instance>      
    <virtual-host>default-host</virtual-host>
    <security-domain>ICSDRest</security-domain>
  </jboss-web>
```

The EAP (7.4.7) is configured with Elytron, offering the security domain (ICSDRest).
Works fine. Access to the Rest service is now secured by the SSL layer.
I also have configured EAP to have a client-ssl-context (see below LDAP).

```
  <client-ssl-contexts>
    <client-ssl-context name="ICLdapSslContext" trust-manager="ICTrustManager"/>
  </client-ssl-contexts>
```

A second EAR+War (ProjectB) should use the Rest service from ProjectA. So ProjectB is a Rest client.

To instanciate the ResteasyClient in ProjectB, I must set the sslContext too (I guess).
I want pick a client-ssl-context from Elytron, if possible.
Is there a way?

Why I want to pick from Elytron?

ProjectA is also dealing with LDAP via ldaps. So ProjectA is a client for LDAP server.
I have configured EAP as a LDAP client like

```
  <dir-contexts>
    <dir-context name="ICLdap" url="<some url>" principal="<query>" ssl-context="ICLdapSslContext">
    <credential-reference clear-text="<some password>"/>
    </dir-context>
  </dir-contexts>
```

So I hope, I can get is a similar way the sslContext from EAP/Elytron.
The idea is to get from Elytron the SSL context and set like

```
  builder.sslContext(mySSLcontext)
```

or create the ReasteasyClient within the context.

Any hints for a EAP beginner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are ProjectA and ProjectB in the same server with the same Elytron configuration?

Comment: Yes, actually both EAR should run in same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution:

I created a new key for my REST client in ProjectB.

```
keytool -genkey -keystore projectB-client.p12 ...
keytool -exportcert -keystore projectB-client.p12 ...
```

Added public key from JBoss/EAP of projectA to projectB-client.p12

```
keytool -keystore projectB-client.p12 -importcert -trustcacerts ...
```

The keystore projectB-client.p12 is placed in EAP standalone/configuration directory.

Added public key from projectB-client.p12 to truststore of JBoss/EAP

```
keytool -keystore app.truststore -importcert -trustcacerts ....
```

With Jboss CLI, I added a new security domain.

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=projectB-client:add
/subsystem=security/security-domain=projectB-client/jsse=classic:add(truststore={password=<...>,url="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.truststore"}, \
  keystore={password=<...>, url="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/projectB-client.p12"}, client-auth=true)
```

This is creating a entry like:

```
<security-domains>
    ...
    <security-domain name="projectB-client">
        <jsse keystore-password="password here" keystore-url="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/projectB-client.p12" truststore-password="password here" truststore-url="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.truststore" client-auth="true"/>
    </security-domain>
</security-domains>
```

In ProjectB, the following code will request the security domain from EAP and getting access to key- and trusmanager without having any password for both.

E.g

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class InitalizerOnStartup {

    private MyService myService;

    // getter

    public void onStart(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object pointless) throws Exception {
        buildRestClient();
    }

    private void buildRestClient () throws Exception {
        final String sdName = "java:jboss/jaas/projectB-client/jsse";
        final URL endPoint = new URL("https://localhost:8443/myUrl");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        JBossJSSESecurityDomain sd = (JBossJSSESecurityDomain) ctx.lookup(sdName);
        if ( sd == null )
            throw new Exception("Can't get EAP security domain - name=" + sdName);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(sd.getKeyManagers(), sd.getTrustManagers(), null);

        ResteasyClientBuilder builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
        builder.sslContext(sslContext);
        ResteasyClient client = builder.build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(endPoint.toURI());
        myService = target.proxy(MyService.class);
    }
}
```

Or use EBJ technique `@Startup`.

I guess, this logic will also work, when having ProjectA + B on different servers (use localhost -> fqdn)

To use JBossJSSESecurityDomain ->

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'org.picketbox:picketbox:5.0.3.Final'  // I use the exact same version from my EAP release, here 7.4.7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an elytron Java security provider that can be used to obtain the elytron SSLContext via the SSLContext.getDefault() call. It is described in this blog post: https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/client-default-ssl-context/

So in your setup, maybe you can create an [elytron client configuration file](https://docs.wildfly.org/30/Client_Guide.html) wildfly-config.xml , where you can specify the ssl-context with the same trust-manager configuration that the "ICTrustManager" uses. You can then give the provider the path to this config file. For example in code like this:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new WildFlyElytronClientDefaultSSLContextProvider(CONFIG_FILE_PATH), 1);
```

Then you can configure it for your ResteasyClient:

```
builder.sslContext(SSLContext.getDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't tried this solution yet. I found another way, see my answer. It will fit to my projects in a similar way, because I also have similar logic dealing from my application with LDAPS as a client and to the LDAP server. So I also need here same logic and use a security domain. But the object (dir-context) will also access the ssl-context. Just created by EAP internally.